# tinylog2 - reconfigure during run

Tags: tinylog

is there a way to reconfigure tinylog2 properties after I already logged some lines ?
I want to change the log file name during run, when the user changes selections (working with diferent files) ,without restart my program.

my code works only first time :

```
private void initLogger(String fileName) {
//        log to file
        Configuration.set("writer","file");
//        set log file name
        if (inFileCheckBox.isSelected()){  // log file name is working file name
            Configuration.set("writer.file",fileName);
        }else{ // log file name by month (MM-YYYY)
            Configuration.set("writer.file", new SimpleDateFormat("MM-yyyy").format(new Date()));
        }
        Logger.info("yow it's : {}", fileName);
    }
```

I tried to shutdown it manualy before I change parameter but it didn't help :

```
ProviderRegistry.getLoggingProvider().shutdown();
```

this is the error I get second time I run the method :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Configuration cannot be changed after applying to tinylog
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

tinylog's native logging provider does not support configuration changes after issuing the first log entry. However, you could create your custom logging implementation by extending or wrapping tinylog's native logging provider [TinylogLoggingProvider](https://github.com/tinylog-org/tinylog/blob/v2.3/tinylog-impl/src/main/java/org/tinylog/core/TinylogLoggingProvider.java) and add your required runtime changing logic by yourself.

You can find a documentation how to register and use a custom logging provider on the tinylog website: https://tinylog.org/v2/extending/#custom-logging-provider

Comment: Understand since v2, the configuration is intentionally made immutable. However, what is the recommended way to change log level at runtime?
E.g. I have many Docker container instances running in k8s cluster. At runtime I see some error logs and want to turn on Debug/Trace level. By default, do I have to rebuild the entire Java app and Docker image and redeploy to the running cluster?

Comment: The recommend way is using a custom logging provider that extends the default TinylogLoggingProvider. Here is a Kotlin example: https://github.com/tinylog-org/tinylog/issues/215#issuecomment-870418371. Only a few lines of code are required.